# How can I add custom color to WordPress Tabs Elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress and cannot find a way to add my custom color to tabs element. I am using weberium theme. I have also tried custom css but it makes no effect on the color of tabs. Everything else can be changed. Please help.

Comment: please provide the URL in which you will need to change the colors

Comment: http://www.buraqsys.com

Comment: you want to change the color of Recent Portfolio section right?

Comment: @Pixlogix no I want to change color of the "What we do" section. That has all the tabs below.

Comment: This https://ibb.co/NFMrZT5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the below css in your theme css file and try important property if not working

```
   .wpb-js-composer .vc_tta-color-blue.vc_tta-style-classic .vc_tta-tab>a {
        background: #333;
    }
```